# Why illegal characters in path?

Tags: c#, file

```
....
case "DOWNLOAD":
if (File.Exists(commandContent)) {
MessageBox.Show(commandContent);
result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(commandContent)); //ERROR
result = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result);          
}
break;
```

And Unhandled Error exception says "illegal characters" in path. The MessageBox shows a correct path

```
  C:\Users\Me\Myfile.exe
```

I tried to do the following :

```
 commandContent = commandContent.replace(@"\",@"\\");
 result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(commandContent)); //ERROR
```

I also tried the following :

```
 commandContent = @""+commandContent+"";
 result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(commandContent)); //ERROR
```

but this doesn't work. And the more strange is that it was working correctly as it is, but once I made some modification in the way I'm inserting commandContent into db (using ajax instead of regular form submit), this problem appears ?

**EDIT:**

I tried to hard code the path using

```
 commandContent = @"C:\Users\Me\file.exe";
```

That worked correctly. How can I force the variable not to contain any illegal characters?

Comment: I'm questioning why you're `base64` encoding an executable and url encoding it...

Comment: Try hard coding the path. Does that work?

Comment: Well. I have supressed that line from my code

Comment: @JonB Yes .. That works.. But I must use a variable instead ?!

Comment: Any chance there are unprintable characters or something else funky in your variable? You might want to set a breakpoint and examine the value in the debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i'm pretty sure that you have \n or \r or \t or ... at the end or beginning of the string `commandContent`

can you do a

```
  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (commandContent)
```

and check each byte?

maybe the ajax call doesn't make a proper string/path

you can use this to find which one

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var commandContent = "C:\\Users\\Me\\file.exe\n";
        var commandContentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(commandContent);
        var invalidPathChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Select(x=>Convert.ToByte(x));

        var found = commandContentBytes.Intersect(invalidPathChars);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. After adding a break point I notice a \n at the end of the string .